# I'm having issues with a software provider, can I ask here for ways to get them to do what I want them to?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I thought that asking here a way to get Microsoft to delete an account they created without my consent would be relevant, as others might have the same problems.

Microsoft is a software-provider and I have issues on my personal computer due to this. So I think it fits the topics of this site.

Of course the answer won't be a command line I would type (that would be too good to be true).

But isn't software and the usage of software more than this?
It's made by people, sold, shared, tempered, used. All of this are human interactions.
And sometimes, we need to talk to people to solve issues.

So is it fair to claim that SuperUser should allow questions about how to solve issues even if there is obviously no technical solutions? And that the solution will come from saying something or doing something to a fellow human?

Comment: Counter to my answer below, if this account is specifically something on your computer and you want to know what it is and how to get rid of it *yourself* then we might be able to help. How to ask someone else to get rid of it is not on-topic. The focus is on *your computer*.

Comment: If you live in the UK or Europe you can invoke GDPR and formally request for MS to delete all your information.

Comment: If you have a problem with your Microsoft account, you need to contact Microsoft directly, through the appropriate channel on their website.  If a question does not have a technical solution it's likely not an appropriate question here at Super User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The problem is a corporate support issue and is not, per our [on-topic page](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

> … about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking

Corporate support would come under the bracket of "IT support" which is specifically excluded by that same help page.

> issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,

While this does broadly apply to *you* supporting IT, it also can be read as *receiving* corporate IT support.  If only *they* can or should help you, then by definition we cannot.

We have a narrow scope in using computer hardware or software, not the broader scape of "dealing with people who happen to write software". That is a pretty huge rabbit hole to deal with and the problem is where to stop. Does a company that once used Excel count as a "software" company? Does a CNC machine count as a "computer" because a person needs to use one to make it work?

It's that sort of problem that the specificity of "computer hardware or software" is trying to get away from.